# strange initialization code in Python

Tags: python

Wondering what below code mean? Does foo and goo initialized as a dictionary?

```
foo = [0] * 128
goo = [False] * 128
```

Comment: In all seriousness, this is when the interactive Python interpreter helps out a lot. If you say `foo = [0] * 5 ; foo` it will dutifully reply `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. If you say `type(foo)` it will respond `<class 'list'>`, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying a list by an integer N creates a new list with the contents of the original list repeated N times.

`[123] * 4` = `[123, 123, 123, 123]`.

So `[0] * 128` gives a 128-item list where each item is `0`.

`[False] * 128` gives a 128-item list where each item is `False`.

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to know if [123] * 4 is a list type object?

Comment: Yes, `[123]` is a sequence of one element so  `* int`  can be applied yielding `[123, 123, 123, 123]`.

Comment: @msw you can multiply a list of any length by an integer. `[1, 2] * 3 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`.